# What does the red pepper icon mean around method icon in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

While writing unit tests I noticed the red pepper icon near the method icon:

[image]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [JetBrains Icon List](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/resources/icons_list/) this is the **Lombok method** icon:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All fields, methods, constructors generated by Lombok library in java has that symbol in IntelliJ.